# correlation between two series

Tags: statistics, correlation

let us consider following two  series

$$y[t]=a_1\sin(\omega_1 t + \phi_1) + a_2\sin(\omega_2 t + \phi_2)+ \cdots + a_p\sin(\omega_p t+\phi_p) + z_1(t)$$

and

$$y_1 [t] = A_1(\sin(\omega_1 t+\phi_1) + A_2 \sin(\omega_2 t+\phi_2) + \cdots + A_p \sin(\omega_p t+\phi_p) + z(t)$$

suppose that  all parameters are fixed,phases even we can consider as  $0$,frequencies are  same,just amplitudes and  random term(white noise) are different,i want to know how strong  statistical relationship  will be  between these two series?i think that  two two series will be  related to each other,as  if we consider  this as  linear equation,then we will get  two linear equation with same  constant values instead of  sinusoidal components and therefore relationship between them will be just linear form  right?or  correlation coefficient between each variable should be strong,level of strongest depend on how  amplitudes are related to each other right?thanks in advance

Comment: Are the amplitudes random?

Comment: no fixed,they are all fixed

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. If the amplitudes are all fixed, but different for the two signals, then the cross correlation between the two signals will be just the product of the non random terms of the two signals and will depend on the relative levels of the amplitudes.

Comment: that means that  if amplitudes are close to each other correlation coefficient will be high right?

Comment: Yes, if their signs are same.

Comment: does this correlation depend on phases? let say phases are different

Comment: Yes, they do depend upon phases.

Comment: Maybe I'll give an answer .

Comment: ok as you like ,welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let, $$y(t)=\sum_{k=1}^p a_i\sin (w_kt+\phi_k)+z(t)\\
y_1(t)=\sum_{k=1}^p A_i\sin (w_kt+\phi_k)+z_1(t)$$
where $z(t),z_1(t)$are i.i.d.$\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)\forall t\in \mathbb{R}$.
The cross correlation between the two processes is $$E(y(t)y_1(t+\tau))=\sum_{i,j}a_iA_j\sin (w_it+\phi_i)\sin (w_j (t+\tau)+\phi_j)$$ The processes are clearly non-stationary. The processes, however become WSS processes if $\phi\sim\mathcal{U}[0,2\pi)$ and are i.i.d.; in that case the cross correlation becomes $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}a_iA_i\cos w_i\tau$$

Comment: yes  exactly i  know that they are nonstationary,but i had  fighting about this  in dsp.stackexchange.com :D